# What are possible patterns for vue3 component export function?

Tags: design-patterns, vuejs3

I'm developing vue 3 table component that will have data export feature. Table component can be nested and parent/higher level components should have ability to trigger export and receive underlying data.

One way to achieve this that comes to my mind is to reference table component from parent component level and call export methods directly on table component.

Another idea would be to watch one of the props which could be incremented and change would trigger export event.

Do you have experience with other patters for this scenario (expose component internal method / feature and consume result in parent component). Do you find any drawback of ideas listed above?

Best regards,
It_man

Comment: For me the best pattern for this is to use a store (pinia or vuex) or at least a reactive variable exported in an other file. This way your data are accessible by each component without spaghetti communication between components

Comment: @jeremycastelli As far as I understand your concept it assumes that table component is bind to store architecture (has to know which prop of the store to use)? When I would like to build "universal component" that could be used in other projects with other stores it wont be possible right?

Comment: yes you are right . With pinia you can create small and independant stores, it's not monolitic like we used to do with vuex. So you can put your store in a file along your component without problem . I didn't know you wanted a portable component, maybe my 2nd method better suit your needs, you can now with vue3 put your reactives, refs, computeds, methods, watchs in a separate file, export them and import them in the components you want and use them. Your components now share common state and methods

Answer (score 0):

Calling the export function from the parent component is a good option. I don't see any downside to it.

I assume you will have an Export button to export the data when the user clicks on it. So adding an Export button right into your `Table` component would be another approach. You can wrap it into a slot to enable the ability to modify from the parent component.

```html
<div @click="exportData()">
   <slot>
      <button> Export </button> 
   </slot>
</div>
```

I don't like the `props` or `vuex/pinia` approach because it is counter-intuitive. Imagine that you change a state then the user gets prompted to download a file. It is not the purpose of a state.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion! Slot - ok, but as far as I understand not related with calling export from parent (just influence the look of export ui trigger inside table component)?

Comment: @ITMan yeah. It is not related to the export function. The first sentence of my answer is the straight answer. The slot approach is what I think is worth mentioning here because it can solve the problem in a cleaner way.